# I want to write a query where user Manually Select AND, OR, NOT

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Very new to laravel and programming.
I want to write a code where user manually select AND OR NOT two times as given in Image, according to there are 3*3 means 9 conditions but I want one condition.

[image] 
[image] 
[image]

AS I cant manually write as follows.

```
//like this
$orwhere = '->orwhere';
$data = AllData::where('BookTitle', 'like', '%'.$request->get('book').$y)
$orwhere('Author', $middle, '%'.$request->get('book').'%')->get();
```

I know there would be some other way, feels like no Idea.

Comment: don't want full code just want some hint, like how to manually use AND OR NOT conditions

Comment: left side drop down is always a Book Title or something else for 3 inputs ?

Comment: You can create an if else condition for AND, OR and NOT on the basis of selected value

Comment: Yes It came in my mind first time but it makes 9 conditions that makes me feel like school boy programming, Just wanted to write some pro code.

Comment: @SaurabhMistry brother, It will change, but It can manually change like where($column, 'like', $request_>get('value')...
So its not a problem.

Comment: Why 9 times is there any add more type of functionality in this or is it limited to 3 only? Can you share that code too?

Comment: @HemantMaurya , please add your html form code

Comment: @KamalPaliwal bhai ji, There are three text box and in between them there are two drop down with and-or-not conditions.

Comment: Loops are also there in php bro

Comment: @SaurabhMistry Sorry for taking time, it was giving code formatting error so uploaded code here http://addedschools.com/hemant.txt